systemd service oom (out of memory) is not triggered
With following steps, I tried to trigger OOM on systemd service, but failed, what is missed? Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions :)

Build a binary which will ask for 3G memory total (30 times, 100M memory one time), put to /opt/test

Build a systemd service with this binary, set 1G memory limitation, and OOMPolicy is kill.


cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/ttt.service
[Unit]
Description=ttt
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/test

MemoryMax=1G
OOMPolicy=kill


Start this service, the binary can get 3G memory, and it is not killed.

The service status is here, you can see that max: 1.0G in it, it is for 1G memory limitation.
# sudo systemctl status ttt.service
● ttt.service - ttt
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ttt.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-12-10 07:56:42 UTC; 15min ago
   Main PID: 360604 (test)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8757)
     Memory: 656.0K (max: 1.0G available: 1023.3M peak: 876.0K)
        CPU: 8ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ttt.service
             └─360604 /opt/test

The service can get 3G (3074372) memory:
# ps -aux | grep test
root      360604  0.0  0.0 3074372 1280 ?        Ss   07:56   0:00 /opt/test

I also tried command dmesg -w, but nothing happens.

You're probably looking at Linux's overcommit feature. When overcommit is enabled (as it is by default), allocated memory is not accounted while it is still empty – because at that point the allocation doesn't actually consume any physical memory yet.
(Glibc allocates memory using mmap() and the system just maps the pages to nothing until the program tries to touch them, which could be done using memfrob(buf, len) for a quick test.)

After filling all the allocated memory (make RSS VSZ at the same size level),  the process can be killed.
$ ps -aux | grep test
root      363460 64.1 13.7 1128696 1044096 ?     Rs   08:58   0:18 /opt/test

1128696 for VSZ
1044096 for RSS
sudo systemctl status ttt.service
× ttt.service - ttt
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ttt.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: oom-kill) since Tue 2024-12-10 08:58:51 UTC; 4min 12s ago
   Duration: 28.168s
    Process: 363460 ExecStart=/opt/test (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 363460 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
        CPU: 18.306s

